# we have a graph $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ defined for $x \in [-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Will it have a relative maxima at $x= -1$ and $x=1$?

the function is not defined for $x<-1$ and $x>1$ so I am having this doubt.

Comment: Why it's not defined outside $[-1,1]$?  A cubic root can be taken for any real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x) = \dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$is undefined at $x = 0$, thus $x = 0$ is the only critical point of this closed interval $[-1,1]$. Thus consider this point of $x = 0$ and the endpoints of $-1,1$ we have the min is $f(0) = 0$, and the max is $f(\pm 1) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using no calculus by simply noting that $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$, while if $x \in (-1,1)$, then $x^2 < 1$, hence $\sqrt[3]{x^2} < 1$.